# Rating Bar and Progress Bar in Android

Tags: android, layout

Im working on a project for a company and facing minor problems based on Rating bar and Progress bar. Is there any possibility of creating custom rating bar and progress bar in vertical position. The following is the image im attaching,trying to seek rating and progress bar on the design mentioned below with colors.

[image: Rating and Progress Bar in different shapes, color and position]

Regards
Rohit

Comment: What is this put on hold as the users dont have the answers or no answers related to this question ?

Answer (score 1):

Vertical progress bars are not supported by default.

For rating bar shown above image you can use like,

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/jreviewarticleuserratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    app:isEditable="false"
    app:star_empty="@drawable/your image"
    app:star_filled="@drawable/your image"
    app:star_half="@drawable/your image"
    app:star_size="25" />
```

Comment: Moradiya Akash Thanks for your reply mate. IS there any other possibility of progress bar implementing in that way and for rating bar are there any sample codes ?

Comment: app:isEditable="false"
                app:star_empty="@drawable/your image"
                app:star_filled="@drawable/your image"
                app:star_half="@drawable/your image"
                app:star_size="25"                                                                          The code doenst work at the app:isEditable not a valid function.